# difference between two milliseconds in C

Tags: c, time

I was wondering whether there is a function in C that takes time in the following format (current date and time in seconds are in Epoch format)

```
a.1343323725
b.1343326383
```

And returns me the result as difference between the two time as hrs:mins:secs

---

Sorry for any confusion, to clarify my point I wrote a code that gets that gets the user's current time execute some block of code and gets the time again. And I was wondering whether the difference could be converted into hrs:mins:sec as a string literal.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        struct timeval tv = {0};
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        printf("%ld \n", tv.tv_sec);
        //Execte some code
         gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What structure do you want hrs:mins:secs provided as?  Or do you want the result as a string?

Comment: What does it mean for a current date to be "in seconds"? Seconds since a certain date? What do you mean the result in hrs:mins:secs? In seconds? Formatted to a string? What does this have to do with milliseconds at all? Be specific!

Comment: This article may help you: http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_17.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to get the time difference in seconds out of the timeval structures that those functions return, using something like this:

```
int diff = a.tv_sec-b.tv_sec;
```

Where a and b were the values returned by gettimeofday.

Next you want to break that down into units of hours, minutes and seconds.

```
int hours=diff/3600;
int minutes=(diff/60)%60;
int seconds=diff%60;
```

Finally we want to get that data into a string, using the snprintf function from

```
#include <stdio.h>
char output[10];
snprintf(output, 10, "%d:%d:%d", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

sprintf words exactly like printf, except the output goes into a string, not onto stdout, and snprintf is the same except it won't write more than n characters into the string, to prevent buffer overflows.
Stitch those together and you've got the job done.

Answer (score 1):

```
 unsigned diff = b-a;
 printf("%u:%u:%u", diff/3600, (diff % 3600)/60, diff % 60);
```

- `diff / 3600` is hours.
- `(diff % 3600) / 60` is remainder minutes
- `(diff % 3600) % 60` equal to `diff % 60` is remainder seconds

Limitation: this code don't work for diffs greater than about 136 years.

Note: It is bad idea to use gettimeofday for the performance meter. The best function to use is clock_gettime with CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock id (It is not affected by wall-clock time change). But beware CLOCK_MONOTONIC don't work in Linux kernels before 2.6. Check clock availability before use.